# How to auto connect wi-fi

Tags: linux, wpa-supplicant

I am using alpine linux. I use following command to connect to WiFi

```
wpa_supplicant -D wext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
udhcpc -i wlan0
```

But after every reboot I have to connect manually. How to connect WiFi automatically after reboot?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148586/discussion-on-question-by-kdm6389-how-to-auto-connect-wi-fi); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by modifying file `/etc/conf.d/wpa_supplicant` adding `-Dwext -iwlan0` to `wpa_supplicant_args=""` as `wpa_supplicant_args="-Dwext -iwlan0"` using `vi`

After rebooting, WiFi connected automatically

Other related files which look like following

- `/etc/network/interface`

  ```
  auto wlan0
  iface wlan0 inet dhcp
      wpa-driver wext
      wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
  ```
- `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

  ```
  ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
  update_config=1
  country=AU

  network={
  ...
  }
  ```

One can use `sed` to do the same:

```shell
sed -i 's/wpa_supplicant_args=.*/wpa_supplicant_args="-Dwext -iwlan0"/g' /etc/conf.d/wpa_supplicant
```

You may also need to run commands

```
rc-update add wpa_supplicant
```

as root.

**Warning: System won't boot if wlan0 is missing during boot-up**